# Nautilus is very slow when there are more than 40 items in a folder

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

Nautilus is very slow when there are more than 40 items in a folder.

It takes quite a long time to open the folder, about 5 seconds. Basically in this folder I only have subfolders which have other folders.

I have used Nautilus in other distros and it wasn't as slow as it is with Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is Nautilus listing so slow when showing thumbnails?](http://askubuntu.com/q/129240/25656).

Comment: In the folder only have folders, no img, txt, video....       Basically I just want to go to some directory, it takes 5 seconds to open one level.   Don't say my laptop is too old, it's duo core 4G memory, open a directory should not be a problem

Comment: At least mention how big the file that you get by running `ls -R > recursive.txt` is?

Comment: Why it's related with file size? I am not opening the file, I am opening folders!!!!

Comment: It's got 316278 line in the recursive.txt, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I put all my program project inside the folder

Comment: Why my title and content was been updated? I only find Ubuntu nautils is slow, I didn't find this issue in the other linux distributions!!!

Comment: Ok, doesn't matter, I only feel ubuntu nautils is slow, I didn't feel about the other linux. Because I am using ubuntu almost everyday.